# Playback of a streamed wave is cut while played in WMP

Tags: audio-streaming, wave, wmp, wmplib

We're using WMPLib as an embedded player in our C# application but this issue occurs also in Windows Media Player.

Our server streams audio and has streaming with offset enabled. Given URL:

```
http://ourserver.com/playback?id=400
```

which returns an octet or x-wave stream (both does not work).

The WMP starts buffering and playing the 2 mins long wave file from given URL (everything works fine) but when I grab and drop the track slider to something about 90% of its length, the playback is cut off and WMP displays general audio error (c00d11b1). When I drop the slider closer (10-20% further) the playback continues without any errors and is played with offset properly. I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

When I'm using the same URL in other media player applications (VLC), no error occurs.

What causes such issue?

TCP packets from this situation:

*WMP=>Server - get the wave*

```
GET http://ourserver.com/playback?id=400
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept: */*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=7e5156ec44280a9210570158c5d31475
User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
Host: 192.168.0.5
```

*Server=>WMP - return file*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Dis; filename="sound.wav"
Content-Length: 833658
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:46:01 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

*The sound is played, we move the slider...
WMP=>Server - get the sound with offset (set in range)*

```
GET http://ourserver.com/playback?id=400
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept: */*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=7e5156ec44280a9210570158c5d31475
Range: bytes=733184-833657
User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
Host: 192.168.0.5
```

*Server=>WMP - returns sound*

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Content-Range: bytes 733184-833657/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Dis; filename="sound.wav"
Content-Length: 833658
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:46:10 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

*The stream continues but WMP cuts off playback and shows error.*

How can we fix this?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the second response, the server is responding with the full octect stream from the beginning. 
Assuming you have control at a low enough level on server side, your server must use `Range: bytes=733184-833657` http header sended by the client to read this range of bytes from `soud.wav` and send it to the client.

I'm not sure about http response headers needed but as a clue: it's the same behaviour of resume a http download.

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1218116.aspx) you can see server side C# code building a Content-Range response.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711922/how-to-play-stream-audio-from-a-blob-in-php?rq=1) you can see PHP code building response.